# Knockout.js - delete all global view models of a specific instance "type"

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, viewmodel

I have an MVC 4 application in which I'm retrieving partial views via ajax and injecting the response html into a div on my page.

Each partial view has a script section in it which instantiates a knockout view model and then binds that view model to a div on the partial view.

I'm noticing that each time I make a request for a partial view, an instance of the previously requested view's view model is staying in memory. Ideally the only view model I'd like to stay in memory is the one that is bound to the partial view that was just requested.

Here are the methods I'm using to get the partial views:

```
getFoo: function () {
    $.get('Home/Foo', null, function (data) {
        ko.cleanNode($('#contentDiv')[0]);
        $('#contentDiv').html(data);
    });
},
getBar: function () {
    $.get('Home/Bar', null, function (data) {
        ko.cleanNode($('#contentDiv')[0]);
        $('#contentDiv').html(data);
    });
}
```

Here are the partial views:

*FOO VIEW*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var fooViewModel = new FooViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(fooViewModel, $('#fooDiv')[0]);
});
</script>

<div id="fooDiv">
    <div data-bind="text:name"></div>
</div>
```

*BAR VIEW*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var barViewModel = new BarViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(barViewModel, $('#barDiv')[0]);
});
</script>

<div id="barDiv">
    <div data-bind="text:name"></div>
</div>
```

And here are the view models:

*FOO VIEW MODEL*

```
function FooViewModel() {
this.name = ko.observable('FOO HERE');
}
_.extend(FooViewModel.prototype, {
    fooEvent: function () {
        console.log('foo event fired');
    }
});
```

*BAR VIEW MODEL*

```
function BarViewModel() {
this.name = ko.observable('BAR HERE');
}
_.extend(BarViewModel.prototype, {
    barEvent: function () {
        console.log('bar event fired');
    }
});
```

Prior to adding `ko.cleanNode` the number of instances of each view model incremented by one with each request. Adding `ko.cleanNode` got the application to only hang onto one instance of each view model, but ideally the only view model in memory would be the one that was brought back in the partial view request.

Does anyone know how I can get rid of the previous view model instance that seems to want to hang around in memory?

Comment: I'm guessing this code is an extremely simplified version of your real code, but I'm wondering about the "delete window['FooViewModel']" line.  Are you trying to delete the definition of the view model, or an instance of the view model?

Comment: That's correct. My actual project is much more complicated so I created a trite example to see if I could see this behavior reproduced and it indeed does. I've since removed the 'delete window["FooViewModel"]' because, as you stated, I don't want to completely remove the definition.

Comment: I don't see anything in your posted code that screams "memory leak", but there could be another reference.  Can you reproduce this in a jsFiddle and post it with your question?

Comment: I will say that this is an unusual pattern.  A more common pattern would be to use something like a web service or WebAPI to return JSON data, and use that data to update your client-side knockout models. Then knockout would update your view automatically without the need to send down more HTML from the server (or need to hunt down memory leaks).

Comment: This pattern is commonly used in single page applications where partial views are loaded asynchronously via ajax requests. The $.get call is calling a MVC controller method which is returning the view. I'm afraid I can't fiddle anything due to the fact that I'm also using MVC compiled controllers.

Comment: I may have misread your OP.  I read it to say you were loading HTML, ko view model, and data with each AJAX call.  I wanted to say that with knockout, you would only load the html template and view model once, and then load only data on subsequent calls and map it to your in-memory model so knockout can update the HTML for you.  In SPAs I tend to rely on an AMD loader like requirejs for this, or Durandal JS.  In any case, I hope you find your leak!